# Including specific paths when using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following code structure:

```
--src
   |--common--include--common---datatype--a_h_file.hpp
   |         |
   |          --src
   |
   |--main_lib
   |    |--------include-----one---one.hpp
   |          |
   |          |---src--------one----one.cpp
   |          CMakeLists.txt
   |---main.cpp
       CMakeLists.txt
```

`main.cpp` uses `one.hpp` without problem.

My `CMakeLists.txt` files are like this

Upper level

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

project(MyProject VERSION 1.0.0)


add_subdirectory(main_lib)

add_executable(myproj main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(myproj PUBLIC mainpub)
```

and the other

```
add_library(mainpub
src/one/one.cpp)

target_include_directories(mainpub PUBLIC include)
```

With this I can use `one.hpp`

My problem is that *by design* it has been decided that `one.hpp` should include `a_h_file.hpp` like this

(one.hpp)

```
#pragma once

float addition(float,float);

#include "common/data_type/a_h_file.hpp"  //<---THIS!

class whatever{
    public:

    int number=1;
};
```

So, my question is how do I modify the CMake files to include the path `/src/common/include` to the paths that are going to be considered in order to be able to use `a_h_file.hpp`?

EDIT: I tried

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

project(MyProject VERSION 1.0.0)
add_library(Common INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(Common INTERFACE common/include)

add_subdirectory(main_lib)

add_executable(myproj main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(myproj PUBLIC mainpub)
```

and in the other

```
add_library(mainpub
src/one/one.cpp)

#target_include_directories(mainpub PUBLIC include ../common/include) 

#target_include_directories(mainpub PUBLIC Common)

#target_include_directories(mainpub PUBLIC include)

target_include_directories(mainpub PUBLIC Common include)
```

but it did not work :(

```
fatal error: common/data_type/a_h_file.hpp: No such file or directory
     #include "common/data_type/a_h_file.hpp"
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

EDIT2:

Modified the second Cmake file to

```
add_library(mainpub
src/one/one.cpp)

target_link_libraries(mainpub PUBLIC Common)

target_include_directories(mainpub PUBLIC include)
```

It did not work either.

Comment: You do realize that multiple directories can be listed as parameters of `target_include_directories`? Either list the other directory in addition to `` or do what Botje suggests...

Comment: I tried to do `target_include_directories(road_pub PUBLIC include ../common/include)` but it didn't work. Error: `common/data_type/a_h_file.hpp: No such file or directory`

Comment: Is the mismatch between `data_type` in your `#include` and `datatype` in your tree output a copy-paste accident? If not, show verbose build output (`cmake --build build --verbose` or `make VERBOSE=1`)

Comment: @Botje Thanks! I did not notice that! I think it will work now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, define an `INTERFACE` target for your common directory in the top-level CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(Common INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(Common INTERFACE common/include)
```

Then just link against it in your targets, which will propagate the include directories:

```
target_link_libraries(mainpub PUBLIC Common)
```

Comment: The second in the main_lib level CMakeLists.txt??? after `target_include_directories(mainpub PUBLIC include)`?

Comment: Yep. For any target that needs the common includes. If you link it as PUBLIC it will automatically be propagated to dependents of the target as well.

Comment: I edited the question with my trial but it didn't work. I must have missed something

Comment: Note that the second  block of code uses **target_link_libraries** to link mainpub and Common, not target_include_directories.

Comment: I see. I tried it again (see EDIT2)